# Label won't show up next to radio button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've added a form on a website with multiple steps. Everything works, but for some reason, the radio buttons that I use in the form won't display the label next to the radio button but below.

Tried to alter the CSS file, but can't seem to find why it is doing that at all. I'm missing something...

```css
body{
  color:#333;
  background:#FFF;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
select.form-control {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #888;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

input[type=radio] {
 height:20px;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
}

textarea,
textarea.form-control {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #888;
}

button.btn {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #2d3e50;
    ;
    border: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

button.btn:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #fff;
}

button.btn:active {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

button.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: #FF0000;
    ;
    color: #fff;
}

button.btn:active:focus,
button.btn.active:focus {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: #FF0000;
    ;
    color: #fff;
}


strong {
    font-weight: 500;
}

.btn-link-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 16px 20px 0 20px;
    background: #26A69A;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-link-1:hover,
.btn-link-1:focus,
.btn-link-1:active {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn-link-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-link-2:hover,
.btn-link-2:focus,
.btn-link-2:active,
.btn-link-2:active:focus {
    outline: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
}

.form-box {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.form-top {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
    background: #2d3e50;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.form-top h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.form-bottom {
    padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
    background: #eee;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.form-bottom:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

form .form-bottom button.btn {
    min-width: 105px;
}

form .form-bottom .input-error {
    border-color: #d03e3e;
    color: #d03e3e;
}

form.registration-form fieldset {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12 form-box">
     <form action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
         <div class="form-top">
           <h3>1. Aantal werknemers binnen je organisatie</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="0">
                                            <label>0 werknemers</label>                                          
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="1-5">
                                            <label>1 - 3 werknemers</label>
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="6-10">
                                            <label>4 - 10 werknemers</label>
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="11-19">
                                            <label>11 - 50 werknemers</label>
                                            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="+50">
                                            <label>meer dan 50 werknemers</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Volgende</button>
                            </div>
     </form>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/diegie/odfv0h6s/1/

Anybody sees where I'm going wrong?

Comment: remove "form-control" class from radio input

Comment: its working for me..  try this agn

Comment: Lol, it's so simple. Why didn't I tried that. Never thought that would be the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
Added grid (you can see it at the end of the css file) and changed position of label and input). Hope it helps. :) Eventually look at grid course.
    `See: https://jsfiddle.net/b76s4tf0/3/`

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at fiddle file, I have added floats and clear property after each group.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/milos44/x64rn32b/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-box">
      <form action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
        <div class="form-top">
          <h3>1. Aantal werknemers binnen je organisatie</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-bottom">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="0" />
                <label>0 werknemers</label>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="1-5" />
                <label>1 - 3 werknemers</label>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="6-10" />
                <label>4 - 10 werknemers</label>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="11-19" />
                <label>11 - 50 werknemers</label>
                <p class="clear"></p>
                <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="q1" id="q1" value="+50" />
                <label>meer dan 50 werknemers</label>
                <p class="clear"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Volgende</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
select.form-control {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #888;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  float: left;
}

textarea,
textarea.form-control {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

button.btn {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #2d3e50;
  border: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #fff;
}

button.btn:active {
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

button.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

button.btn:active:focus,
button.btn.active:focus {
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.btn-link-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 16px 20px 0 20px;
  background: #26a69a;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-link-1:hover,
.btn-link-1:focus,
.btn-link-1:active {
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-link-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-link-2:hover,
.btn-link-2:focus,
.btn-link-2:active,
.btn-link-2:active:focus {
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
}

.form-box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.form-top {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
  background: #2d3e50;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #fff;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.form-top h3 {
  color: #fff;
}

.form-bottom {
  padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
  background: #eee;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.form-bottom:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
    0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16),
    0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

form .form-bottom button.btn {
  min-width: 105px;
}

form .form-bottom .input-error {
  border-color: #d03e3e;
  color: #d03e3e;
}

form.registration-form fieldset {
  display: none;
}

p.clear {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
}

label {
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```